# How do I know whether Castor uses Xerces for unmarshalling objects from XML by chunks?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax, xerces, castor

I am using [Castor](http://castor.codehaus.org/reference-guide.html) to unmarshall XML objects. According to its documentation it uses Xerces parser by default. I would like Castor to unmarshall objects as it parse new elements, and not marshall hundreds of objects into the memory. This is because I am going to unmarshall a huge XML file.

Is there any way for me to ascertain how Castor parse an XML document ?

Comment: It uses Xerces. Xerces is a DOM parser. So it uses DOM.

Comment: @EJP SAX Version 2 is also supported by Xerces. See http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/